# Is the rate of new job creation and destruction slowing down in the US?

Tags: united-states, economics

Marc Andreessen said in an [interview](https://youtu.be/qg6-mdcVBeo?t=35m28s) with Tim Ferriss:

> Most people would guess it's rising. technology is having an ever greater impact right and so things feel like they are accelerating it's a big theme in the political season: [...] Dramatic things are happening that are historically unprecedented. [...] Almost everybody believes that change is increasing.[...]
>
> Actually it turns out that in the American economy the reverse is happening. The rate of both job creation and destruction is falling and has been falling for decades.

Is the change of jobs via job creation and destruction really going down in the US?